# Found weil pairing. Index Calculus method on the results of weil pairing

Tags: cryptanalysis, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, pairings

Consider Elliptic curve with p = 59, A = 1, B= 0, P = (25,30) and Q=(35,31).

So I tried to solve this using MOV attack.

The torsion point for them E[5] is R(-25,30i) where is sqroot -1

Chosen two points (40,54) and (48+55i,28+51i)

So calculated weil pairing e(P,R) which is (46+i56) and e(Q,R) is (42+i19)

Now my problem is how do I try index calculus method on these complex numbers.
Can any body help me to solve this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm

Comment: I understood Index calculus method. but how to use index calculus method on numbers like 46+i56